# Is there any way I can find mac updates location and downlad them manually?

Tags: macos, mac, updates, internet-speed

I have a very slow internet connection that gives me lost signal every few minutes and it get's even worse when it comes to update my mac. Apple only allows you to download updates using its stupid update downloader but they have left no alternative way for people like me who get this error every time they try to update something: "A network error has occurred. Check your Internet connection, and then try again." with no resume button.
or even worse a corrupted package that can't be installed.

I am looking for someway to track down the location of files that must be downloaded, and then download them manually or on a VPS with a higher internet speed and then transfer them to my machine.

Is there any way to do this? 
Is there any application for helping with such problems?
Any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually download patches from apples website.

[Link to apple](http://support.apple.com/downloads/)

Comment: You are awesome, but there is one little problem left, the updates that I want to download are located at 
system preferences > text to speech > system voices > customize
It adds new voices to your system. I don't know what to search for at http://support.apple.com/downloads/